# How to change syntax color on remix?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am confused how to change syntax color on remix because my default color syntax does not apply when it call functionName, .call and etc.

This is my code:

```
function checkBookings(uint256 id, string[] memory newBookings) private view returns (bool){ 
    for (uint i = 0; i < newBookings.length; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < rentals[id].datesBooked.length; j++) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(rentals[id].datesBooked[j])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(newBookings[i]))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function addDatesBooked(uint256 id, string[] memory newBookings) public payable {
    require(id < counter, "No such Rental");
    require(checkBookings(id, newBookings), "Already Booked For Requested Date");
    require(msg.value == (rentals[id].pricePerDay * 1 ether * newBookings.length) , "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

    for (uint i = 0; i < newBookings.length; i++) {
        rentals[id].datesBooked.push(newBookings[i]);
    }

    payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
    emit newDatesBooked(newBookings, id, msg.sender, rentals[id].category,  rentals[id].imgUrl);
}

function getRental(uint256 id) public view returns (string memory, uint256, string[] memory){
    require(id < counter, "No such Rental");

    rentalInfo storage s = rentals[id];
    return (s.name,s.pricePerDay,s.datesBooked);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "default color syntax does not apply"? It seems the color depends on the theme. There's a settings button on the bottom-left where you can select a theme. If the theme doesn't display properly you should report the error in their gitub repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your darkmode extension in Chrome if you see plain white instead of syntax highlighting.